# ツアーページにMarkdownが正しく機能していない部分があります

Tags: バグ, 完了, markdown

「実用的な疑問に対する繊細な回答を得る」のあたりにこう表示されています：

> [image: 機能していないMarkdown]

下の部分の`*`に囲まれた斜体が太字になっていません。下記のほうがいいのではないでしょうか。

> *改善が必要な質問は、誰かが編集するまで**クローズ（閉鎖）**されることがあります。*

バグの原因は`）`と`**`の連続です。[Markdown change: Intra-word emphasis now works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240354/224428)のSome details第２番を参照してください。`**...**`の代わりに`<b>...</b>`を使えば治ると思います。

（日本語が下手ですみません。）

Comment: あら！これを一回直したのに！ちょっと確認してみます。

Answer (score 3):

Markdownではスペースがないとこれになってしまいます。それを治すには他のケースに問題が発生するため、手動でこの場合に直しました。